# How do I populate a combo box from a column in my excel spread sheet?

Tags: excel, combobox, spreadsheet, vba

I have two excel spreadsheets, one has a combobox, the other one has a list of department names. I need to populate the combobox with the department names. How do I acheive this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? :)

Comment: Do you need to use a combobox? You can achieve that with data validation as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a VBA Code:

```
Dim vArr as Variant
Dim i as Integer
vArr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Sheets(2).Range("A2:A10").value)
With Sheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
     .Clear
     For i = Lbound(vArr) to Ubound(vArr)
        .AddItem vArr(i)
     Next i
End With
```

Here is the most simpler way to load the combobox, given your department range will not be empty...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets(1).ComboBox1.List = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A10").Value
End Sub
```

or  within Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ComboBox1.List = Sheets(2).Range("A2:A10").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: How would someone do this with a range along 1 row only? I need to add 5 cells from a single Row to a comboBox