# VBA - Error 381 while trying delete items from combobox

Tags: excel, vba, forms, combobox

I've tried by hours to cope with this error, search solutions, but nothing is clear for me.

1. I've imported successfully items from Excel to combobox (>19 appearances)
2. Now I have duplicates in combo. I wanna iterate by Excel sheet, compare with Combobox & remove unnecessary items (except single one)
3. I have

> error 381 - Could not get the Column property array index.

```
Dim N As Long, K As Long, counter As Long
With Sheets("Główne")
    N = .Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim ostatnia As Long

ostatnia = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To ostatnia
    Range("I" & i + 1).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(L:L,L" & i + 1 & ")"
Next

ComboBox1.Clear
For K = 1 To N
    If Cells(K + 1, 9).Value > 19 Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets("Główne").Cells(K + 1, 12).Value
    End If
Next K

Range("I2:I" & ostatnia).Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'############### problem is somewhere below ##############'
For S = 2 To N
    counter = 1
    For iteracjalista = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ComboBox1.Column(0, iteracjalista) = Sheets("Główne").Cells(S + 1, 12).Value Then

             If Sheets("Główne").Cells(S + 1, 9).Value > counter Then
                ComboBox1.RemoveItem 1
                counter = counter + 1
             End If

        End If

    Next iteracjalista
Next S
```

Probably problem is in last part of code. But I have no idea how I should fix it.
Could you help me?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392122/how-do-i-populate-a-combo-box-from-a-column-in-my-excel-spread-sheet

Answer (score 0):

In place of this Code

```
For K = 1 To N
    If Cells(K + 1, 9).Value > 19 Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem Sheets("Główne").Cells(K + 1, 12).Value
    End If
Next K
```

Use this Code - It eliminates Duplicates before populating the ComboBox

```
   Dim xList As String, xVal As String

   ' The following populates the ComboBox with Unique Values - No Duplicates
     xList = ""
     ' We are using the colon character ":" as a separator
     ' You may wish to use something else
     For K = 1 To N
        xVal = Cells(K + 1, 9).Value
        If xVal > 19 Then
           If InStr(1, xList, ":" & xVal, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
              xList = xList & ":" & xVal
           End If
        End If
     Next K
     xList = Mid(xList, 2)  ' Remove the leading : character
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Glówne").ComboBox1.List = Split(xList, ":")
   ' Done
```

Then you can takeout all the existing code for deleting duplicates from the ComboBox .... All the following can be deleted

```
'############### problem is somewhere below ##############'
For S = 2 To N
    counter = 1
    For iteracjalista = 0 To ComboBox1.ListCount - 1

        If ComboBox1.Column(0, iteracjalista) = Sheets("Główne").Cells(S + 1, 12).Value Then

             If Sheets("Główne").Cells(S + 1, 9).Value > counter Then
                ComboBox1.RemoveItem 1
                counter = counter + 1
             End If

        End If

    Next iteracjalista
Next S
```